# Import&Share a formula from another google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create some google sheets based on formulas imported from a "master" google sheet.

The target is to have an unique google sheet with all the formulas where i can just update once to spread the "update" to all connected google sheets used from third party people.

I tryed several solutions like indirect and importrange, but i'm stuck since you cannot use formulas inside indirect

Example:

```
=INDIRECT(importrange("<URL>";""FORMULAS!B1"");TRUE)
```

Where B1 in "FORMULAS" sheet has the content of a formula (for example b2+b3)

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible within Google Sheets. You have to use scripts.

Comment: Thankyou, i'll try to study the getformula/setformula.
My target is also to keep "secret" the formula btw

Comment: r u looking for excel based solution too?

Comment: no, only google sheet atm

Answer (score 1):

I fixed (partially) with this trick, using scripts

```
function onEdit() { 
var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("url sheet origin");
var sheet = sheetActive.getSheetByName("name of sheet");
var src = sheet.getRange("cell origin");
var str = src.getValue(); 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet target');  
var cell = sheet.getRange("cell target");
cell.setFormula(str);              
}
```

The only problem is that i want to HIDE the original formula...
In this way the script imports entirely the formula from the original sheet and i would prefer to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Create two files `Private1` & `Public1` on google sheet. Public1 is the version everyone can see (editable share link),`Private1` is the version only u can see.

### Setup

1. In cell A1 of `Public1`, enter value 5.
2. r-click the cell > get link from this cell.
3. Share the `Public1`, where the user can edit. (or view only if u want).
4. In cell A1 of `Private1`, enter `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd1","A1")` where the link is coming from step2.
5. In cell A2 of `Private1`, enter a formula that manipulate value of A1. (I use `=A1^3`)
6. r-click the cell > get link from this cell.
7. In cell A2 of `Public1`, enter `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd2","A2")`, where the link is coming from step 6.

Note : at some time of the step gsheet may ask for permission to the linked sheet. Just allow it (since all the user - urself for now)

### Test

Using the link created in step3 above, have the user to open the `Public1`file, and enter/edit the value in cell A1. Result will come out it cell A2 after a short delay.

Please share if it works/understandable/not. ( :

---

### Limitation

This method demonstrate 1 formula that can only be use for 1 cell/value/output at a time. To make it work for the next file/cell, just duplicate the step using the same `Private1' file.

This way, `Private1` file with formula in it not visible to third party people. Sample of [mine](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zkz4kRsXCjY6_J04Qnh0MS-KM8tVoR2DuIXzSivhmPY/edit#gid=0).. (I think u can guess what the formula is already.)

Comment: This should work! I'll tell ya after some tests :)

Comment: Mhhh this is too much tricky since i need multiple (and anonymous) public sheets.

Comment: This is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kIumHDPYy3d7dkL895bOQjbFLP66lSzGdI20YGNmkx0/edit?usp=sharing) to my `Public1` file.. u may test if you can view the formula in my `Private1` file. | Without using an API service, this is the best way I can think of to 'hide' the source formula.